# How to cancel Picasso requests after fragment transitions in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, picasso

I have a fragment with a gridview, which loads say 20 images simultaneously using an adapter. I want to make sure that unfinished Picasso requests terminate gracefully when fragment has disappeared/disposed.

Question

1. Is this automatically handled by Picasso framework (so I don't have to worry)
2. How to implement cancel all Picasso requests on dispose?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do some thing like below, if you want to perform any operation like you asked;

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("http://some.example.com")
.tag(YourTag)
.into(YourImageView)
```

When you want to resume then in onResume() call

```
picasso.resumeTag(YourTag);
```

When you want to pause then in onPause() call

```
picasso.pauseTag(YourTag);
```

When you want to cancel then in onStop() or in onDestroy() call

```
picasso.cancelTag(YourTag);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is very similar to Picasso (they have almost the same API) and offers lifecycle binding for request.

You just call `Glide.with(fragment).load(...).into(imageView);`.

[Here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) you have nice article about differences between Glide and Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to elaborate on @Akbar 's answer in that I couldn't get it to work  because I had no "picasso" instance.
So here's my solution. Initialize the same way, then to cancel:

```
Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(YourImageView);
```

Bonus: 
if you're having issues getting the context (I know I did), or wondering what it is, you can do this in a fragment:

```
Context context = getView().getContext();
```

Hope it helps