# Understanding picasso & recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, picasso

I am trying to understand how picasso behaves with recyclerview with ImageViews.

Is it possible when reusing ViewHolder picasso load old image. I mean:
`mPicasso.load(url1).into(imageView); 
 mPicasso.load(url2).into(imageView);` 
Which image will be loaded url or url2?

How can I cancel image loading process? I mean

```
mPicasso.load(url1).into(imageView); // Start image loading
..
// Image loading not finished, but
// ViewHolder detaches
// Should I remove any pending image loadings here or picasso will do it automatically?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but are there any build-in trigger for picasso to cancel loading when view detaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Picasso is good libarary and handles much of the programming headache itself. I have not used Picasso , as I really enjoy working with [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

I think picasso will be handling its cancel operation once the view is recycled. If not so then you can easily do it with one of the procedure discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629979/how-to-cancel-picasso-requests-after-fragment-transitions-in-android).Please try this and let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks for answer! I think picasso can't know when our view holder is detached. So I should cancel requests manually.

Comment: then check out the link , That is how the you can cancel the request

Answer (score 0):

If your looking forward to cancel Picasso request on ViewHolder when ViewHolder gets detached then you can use `cancelRequest()` do something like this in your adapter.

```
 @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder)
        {
            super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
            Picasso.with(holder.notificationBannerIV.getContext()).cancelRequest(holder.notificationBannerIV);
        }
```